# Prove the image of the Joukowski map is a hyperbola, and at which points is it conformal.

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry

Consider the map

$$f(z):=\frac{1}{2}(z+\frac{1}{z})$$

and show that $f(B)$ is a hyperbola where $B=\{re^{i \theta}: \text{$r>1$ is variable and $\theta$ fixed}\}$

So I know I have to substitute in for $z$ thus I have

$$f(re^{i\theta})=\frac{1}{2}(re^{i \theta} + \frac{1}{re^{i \theta}})$$

So do I combine the terms inside the parenthesis and set it equal to say $X+iY$ then set real parts equal and imaginary parts equal?

I.e., $X=\frac{1}{2}(r+\frac{1}{r})\cos \theta, Y = \frac{1}{2}(r-\frac{1}{r})\sin \theta$ then do I use $\cos^2 \theta + \sin^2 \theta=1$?

Sorry if this is a duplicate, I couldn't find one like it. Also, at which points is the map angle preserving? is it all the $z$ such that

$$f'(z) \neq 0$$

also, how do I show $X^2-Y^2=1$?

I keep getting

$$X^2-Y^2=\frac{r^2}{4}(\cos^2 \theta - \sin^2 \theta)+ \frac{1}{4r^2}(\cos^2 \theta - \sin^2 \theta)+ \frac{1}{2}.$$

any help??

Comment: isn't it $\frac{1}{2}(r \cos \theta +r i \sin \theta + \frac{1}{r} \cos \theta - i \frac{1}{r} \sin \theta)= \frac{1}{2}(\cos \theta(r+\frac{1}{r}) + i \sin \theta(r-\frac{1}{r}))=X+iY$ then $X = \frac{1}{2}(r+\frac{1}{r}) \cos \theta$ while $Y = \frac{1}{2}(r-\frac{1}{r})\sin \theta$? @Laci

Comment: Yeah it is corrected so i deleted my comment.

Comment: how do I show $X^2-Y^2=1$? @Laci given $\theta$ is fixed and $r>1$.

Comment: The equation for a general hyperbola is $\frac{x^2}{a^2}-\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$. I think if you choose $a=2 \text{cos}(\theta)$ and $b=2\text{sin}(\theta)$, then it will satisfy the equation.

Comment: Maybe $2$ is not the right constant I’m calculating in my head. :)

Comment: I don't think the constant matters, does it? @Laci I think maybe setting $a=\cos \theta, b= \sin \theta$ might do the trick, let me compute it out!

Comment: @Laci that did the trick!! I end up with $1$!!

Comment: Perfect. :) Also, yes for a holomorphic map, if $f’(z)\neq 0$, then $f$ preserves the angles. One can prove this by calculating the jacobian of $f$ and since $f$ satisfies the cauchy-riemann equations one sees that if the jacobian is not zero then it is a composition of a rotation and multiplication with a positive number. :)